# Issue with selenium CheckBox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
params = {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': os.getcwd()}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
driver.get("https://auth.opus.pro/login?state=hKFo2SA3bDZPNUtIVHR5dTBaaE9ScnhQLUp0WDExbXFRLW9xeaFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgNFhvUXh4dzF1WndnZHRCbU02TDg4dkp3V3FQUWRZVXmjY2lk2SB5a1RuRGVlcDN5QmlXRXI1dUd0MDRmcFlESW9pT3RyWQ&client=ykTnDeep3yBiWEr5ugt04fpYDIoiOtrY&protocol=oauth2&scope=openid%20profile%20email&display=page&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclip.opus.pro%2Fauth%2Fcallback&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fopuspro.us.auth0.com%2Fapi%2Fv2%2F&loginIframeSrc=https%3A%2F%2Fclip.opus.pro%2Fauth%2Foauth%2Flogin%3Futm_medium%3D%26utm_source%3D&response_type=code&response_mode=query&nonce=Wjd6RnpLS19NUEREQjRRVGdYWERMX0ZXRDQ5dXphbzk1UzlBNUd6flFqOQ%3D%3D&code_challenge=NmqJqIM7MZaZuHdGBOhrEJ8tnQQUzg0XyxgNzC6gMf8&code_challenge_method=S256&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAtcmVhY3QiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMi4yLjEifQ%3D%3D")
time.sleep(5)

# Switch to the iframe containing the Cloudflare security challenge
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='Widget containing a Cloudflare security challenge']")))

# Click the challenge stage
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='challenge-stage']"))).click()
```

**Issue Description:**
I am facing difficulties with the provided Selenium script when interacting with a page containing a Cloudflare security challenge. Even after attempting to extend the timeout to 60 seconds, the problem persists. Your insights and assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

**Anticipated Solution:**
I anticipate being able to successfully address and resolve this issue with your guidance. Thank you in advance for your help!